# Executing a for loop inside PGF axis when #1 is in use

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfmath, axis

`\foreach` does not work inside PGF, so the alternative seems to be  `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach`. My issue is that I want to define my own macros that will be inserted into the axis environment, something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\plotsine#1#2#3{
    \addplot[name path=F1, domain=0:360, samples=100, draw=#3, line width=1.0] 
    ({ x*3.14/180 }, { sin(x*#2) });
    % Want to insert a loop here, but how?
    % Cannot use \foreach
    %\foreach \i in {0,...,#2+1}
    %{
    %   \node (#1\i) at ($(\i,0)$) {};
    %}
    % This doesn't work because symbol #1 is overloaded
    %\pgfplotsinvokeforeach {1,2,...,#2+1} { 
    %   \node (#1) at (#1,0) {#1};
    %}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis equal,hide axis]
\plotsine{N1}{3}{red}
\plotsine{N2}{5}{blue}
\plotsine{N3}{0}{black}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In this example, I want `\plotsine{}{}` to be usable inside the axis environment so I can plot multiple on an axis very quickly. I want to run a loop inside, for instance to place a node at every $x$-intercept
I cannot use `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` because it explicitly relies on access to `#1`, which clashes.

Is there any alternatives for loops in this environment?

Comment: Besides the undefined macro your code can‘t compile. Please add the missing parts.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand what the output should look like, but if you need to refer to an argument of a nested macro defintion, you should add another `#` to the relevant placeholder, so `#1` would become `##1`.

Apart from that, please note that `pgfplots` already loads the `tikz` package, so there is no need to load `tikz` again. Also, it is advised to tell the `pgfplots` package that it should use a compatibility mode that allows for the use of the most recent functionality. This is important here, because it allows you to use a simple notation of, say `(1,0)` to position a node at the relevant position on the axis. Otherwise you would need to use `(axis cs:1,0)`.

So, you code could look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\def\plotsine#1#2#3{
    \addplot[domain=0:360, samples=100, draw=#3, line width=1.0] 
        ({ x*3.14/180 }, { sin(x*#2) });

    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach {1,2,...,#2+1} { 
       \node (##1) at (##1,0) {#1};
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[axis equal,hide axis]
        \plotsine{N1}{3}{red}
        \plotsine{N2}{5}{blue}
        \plotsine{N3}{0}{black}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Which would result in the following output (which I am not sure is what you aim for):

[image]